# how to get percent from a column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a data set with two columns: index (which is the country name) and user_country (which is the count of total users by country).

I need to get the percentage of users by country but I'm not sure how to get it. As I have 104 countries I think the best way is to create a for loop but I don't know how to build it.

Data sample:

```
  index user_country
0   es  329825
1   us  129189
2   pe  20122
3   cl  13762
4   mx  9975
5   co  8968
6   do  4114
7   ar  3724
8   ec  2698
9   uy  1452
10  cr  112
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need divide summed values and then multiple by `100`:

```
df['per'] = df['user_country'].div(df['user_country'].sum()).mul(100)
print (df)
   index  user_country        per
0     es        329825  62.950790
1     us        129189  24.657166
2     pe         20122   3.840509
3     cl         13762   2.626632
4     mx          9975   1.903840
5     co          8968   1.711643
6     do          4114   0.785203
7     ar          3724   0.710767
8     ec          2698   0.514943
9     uy          1452   0.277130
10    cr           112   0.021376
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @jazrael! Anotherone: how to convert this 62.950790 into 62.95% ? Thanks

Comment: @AngeloMerkel - Then use `df['per'] = df['user_country'].div(df['user_country'].sum()).mul(100).round(2).astype(str).add('%')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['percentage']=df.user_country*100/sum(df.user_country)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.